# Flash and php become very slow, same code

Tags: php, flash, request, response

I did a flash application that has a login form in flash, and authenticates in php. That was 3 months ago, and the sending requests and response is very fast -- that is, when i click submit button, within 3 - 5 seconds it will have a response from php.

Recently, I did another login in flash, using similar code as I previously have done. Now, the sending request and respond is very long, each time the server may take up to 10 seconds to respond. Why is it taking so long yet the previous one is fast?

Same host, same php files, similar swf (not much changes in swf).

Comment: Not enough info. Try profiling the code and using Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Firebug to tell you actual request/response time to see if delay is server side or client.

Comment: after loading the page with Firebug open, you should see the times for each individual server request (under the "Console" tab).  Like when I reloaded this page, it shows "GET http://stackoverflow.com/blah/blah  200 OK  89ms".  The last value being the elapsed time -- at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: You can also check at the Net panel what fases are slow, like is it the connection instantiation, or the responding. The former denotes a problem in connection or the server software, the latter a script or php-runtime problem.